# Vb .net TextBox and checkedbox

Tags: vb.net, textbox, checked

everyone

My question is very simple, but I'm racking my brains. In a form I have a Textbox and a CheckBox. I'm validating the event if the textbox is not filled, it shows the message that must be filled in but if you didn't fill the textbox but selected the checkbox, don't check if you filled the textbox. Remembering is Vb .Net.
I've already tried it in the LostFocus, Leave events.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_LostFocus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.LostFocus
   If TextBox1.Text.Trim().Length <> 0 And CheckBox1.Checked Then
      TextBox1.Region = New Region(New Rectangle(2, 2, TextBox1.Width - 4, TextBox1.Height - 4))
      TextBox1.BackColor = Color.Yellow
      ErrorProvider1.SetError(TxtPatrimonio, "Null" & vbCrLf & "Complete date.")
   Else
      TextBox1.BackColor = Color.White
      TextBox1.Region = Nothing
      ErrorProvider1.SetError(TextBox1, "")
   End If
End Sub
```

When you select the checkbox and the textbox loses focus but the checkbox did not change the value checked to true. I don't know if it was clear.

Comment: How about writing a single validation method that validates all your controls, and call it from each of the controls involved in the validating method?

Comment: You shouldn't be handling the `LostFocus` event at all. As the documentation clearly states, that's not for application developers. You handle `Leave` if you want to do something when a control loses focus, but that's not where you do validation anyway. You handle the `Validating` event to perform validation. You can set `e.Cancel` to `True` to prevent the control losing focus, but you don't have to do that. You can put different code in each control's event handler or, if the code is the same, either call a common method or just use a single event handler for both.

Answer (score 1):

You should handle the Validating event of the controls ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.validating)). Inside the event handler, you would perform your business logic and if the logic fails then you would cancel the event arguments and set your error provider.

Also, as a side-note, you should really stop using legacy Visual Basic methods and patterns.

Take a look at this example:

```vb
Private Sub Controls_Validating(sender As Object, e As ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Validating, CheckBox1.Validating
    If (String.IsNullOrWhitespace(TextBox1.Text) AndAlso Not CheckBox1.Checked) Then
        e.Cancel = True
        ErrorProvider1.SetError(TextBox1, $"Null{Environment.NewLine}Complete Date")
    End If
End Sub
```

Side-Note number 2, if you're asking for a date, then use the DateTimePicker and set the Format to a date only format. Remember, always use the right control.

**Update**

In my comments, the OP asked how to make this more generic so that the form can use any number of controls. This was my response:

1. Remove the handles clause from the method
2. Create a form level variable that is a dictionary where the key is the control and the value is a function that checks if it is "valid"
3. In the form's Load event, loop over each key in the dictionary and use AddHandler to bind the control's validating event to the existing function
4. In the existing function, replace the logic with looping over each value in the dictionary and check if every value returns true. If not, then cancel the validating event

For example:

```vb
Private Delegate Function IsControlInValid() As Boolean
Private ReadOnly controlValidations As New Dictionary(Of Control, IsControlInValid) From {
    {TextBox1, New IsControlInValid(Function() String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TextBox1.Text) AndAlso Not CheckBox1.Checked)},
    {CheckBox1, New IsControlInValid(Function() String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TextBox1.Text) AndAlso Not CheckBox1.Checked)} ', etc...
}

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    For Each item In controlValidations.Keys
        AddHandler item.Validating, AddressOf Controls_Validating
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Controls_Validating(sender As Object, e As ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs)
    Dim failsValidation = controlValidations.Values.Any(Function(isControlInvalidFunction) isControlInvalidFunction())
    If (failsValidation) Then
        e.Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. This is really how I wanted to handle validations,
as I'm new to programming, how would I call the function you passed as an example?

Comment: @AlvarezSantos - It would be called automatically since the handles clause contains `TextBox1.Validating` and `CheckBox1.Validating`

Comment: Understand how to use. Thanks for your time in responding to me.

Comment: And how would you extend it to be more generic. Pass control(TextBox) if the form has more textbox to reuse function. @David

Comment: First, remove the handles clause. Next, create a form level variable that is a dictionary where the key is the control and the value is a function that checks if it is "valid". Then, in the form's Load event, loop over each key in the dictionary and use AddHandler to bind the control's validating event to the existing function. Then in the existing function, replace the logic with looping over each value in the dictionary and check if every value returns true. If not, then cancel the validating event. I will update my post with an example.